# Can we use WHERE when inserting new row in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I am writing program in asp.net about managing seminar rooms. In my reservation table, there are reservation id, client id. room id, dateIn and dateOut.I try to insert row if and only if  dateIn and dateOut of new entity does not overlap with existing ones

I used MySql 8.0

```
INSERT INTO reservations (client_id, room_id, date_in, date_out) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM user WHERE first_name=@fname AND last_name=@lname), @roomId, @dateIn, @dateOut) WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT FROM reservations WHERE ((@dateIn >= date_in AND @dateIn <= date_in) OR (@dateOut >= date_out AND @dateOut <= date_out))) LIMIT 1
```

Error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT FROM reservations WHERE (('2019-07-22 11:00:00' >= dat' at line 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use INSERT SELECT format, but then you must check the number of inserted rows in order to know if insert was successfull

```
INSERT INTO reservations (client_id, room_id, date_in, date_out) 
SELECT id, @roomId, @dateIn, @dateOut 
FROM user 
WHERE first_name=@fname 
   AND last_name=@lname 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * 
      FROM reservations 
      WHERE date_out >= @dateIn 
         AND date_in <= @dateOut
   )
```

Also I fixed your overlap logic.
Condition `((@dateIn >= date_in AND @dateIn <= date_in)` is only true when `@dateIn` is equal to date_in.